# Git: Could not reset submodule index when checking out

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-checkout, git-index

I'm trying to checkout a specific commit ID along with all its submodules.

```
git checkout --recurse-submodules 7fdb9221d958acda289904951fe6d37873e8cfbf
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
fatal: not a git repository: ../../.git/modules/components/RxINDICOMMetric1Msg
fatal: could not reset submodule index
```

Any help would be appreciated